# kvm guest cannot initialize network

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization

I'm running a kvm ubuntu guest inside ubuntu both 12.04. Using KVM manager for this.
Initially everything was fine, could connect from the guest to the internet, the host all right. But all of a sudden the guest cannot initilize the network any longer during boot-up. Can't acquire IP, can't connect. On the host machine I'm not experiencing any network issues.

My virtual machine settings:

```
Source device: Virtual network 'default': NAT
Device model: Hypervisor default
```

ifconfig -a output:

```
eth0    Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 52:54:00:aa:85:fa
        inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:feaa:85fa/64 Scope:Link
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
        RX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:3729 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
        RX bytes:870 (870.0 B) TX bytes:810226 (810.2 KB)

lo      Link encap: Local Loopback
        inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
        inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
        RX packets:2800 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:2800 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
        RX bytes:229312 (229.3 KB) TX bytes:229312 (229.3 KB)
```

Comment: What is the result of `ifconfig -a` from inside the guest? and from inside the host?

Comment: edited the question including the output

Comment: What is inside your /etc/network/interfaces?

Comment: auto lo<new line>iface lo inet loopback

Comment: Start by configuring your eth0 interface

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue?

Comment: Not really. I bounced the box and it has been working fine. But my gut feeling tells me I'm going to have this problem again soon. I don't know yet what's causing it.

Comment: Ok so looks like the culprit is openstack. After a fresh reboot everything works. As soon as I launch openstack (devstack) the subsequently booted quests won't be able to initialize their eth0. Shutting down openstack (unstack.sh) does not help.